# How to only allow AWS IoT subscriptions to topics under Cognito user id (sub)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito, aws-iot

I want my backend to be able to directly send messages to authenticated users. Which means I need to limit the users to only subscribe on topics under their own identifiers. Ideally, to my currently limited understanding, I would have a policy that has the user `sub` as a variable:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Connect",
        "iot:Publish",
        "iot:Receive",
        "iot:GetThingShadow",
        "iot:UpdateThingShadow",
        "iot:DeleteThingShadow"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Subscribe"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:949960872797:topicfilter/user/${cognitoUserSub}/someTopic"
    }
  ]
}
```

If ultimately the cognito identifier is not an option for this policy, please advise me of what other identifier i would provide. Whichever it is, i need to be able to somehow obtain it based on the user's cognito identifier (the `sub`).

Note that my knowledge in this regard is very limited, so I understand that I might be off by quite a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered on AWS forum https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=268115

For details on how to use cognito with AWS IoT also check https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=224268