# AWS IoT - Restrict topic to user's Cognito ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iot

I've been trying to restrict `Publish`/`Receive` permissions to a IoT topics to a user's Cognito ID.

In my application, I'm creating topics that look something like `messenger/{cognitoUserId}` (e.g. `messenger/us-east-1:fa610fd5-4fab-4511-834b-8f1198744efb`).

So in my IAM Policy I'd like to specify that only users whose Cognito ID is contained in the topic have `Publish`/`Receive` permissions for that topic.

This is what my IAM Policy currently look like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iot:Connect",
                "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
                "cognito-sync:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iot:Receive",
                "iot:Publish"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:123456789:topic/messenger/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:123456789:topicfilter/messenger/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "iot:Receive",
                "iot:Publish"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:123456789:topic/messenger/*",
            "Condition": {"StringNotLike": {"iot:topicfilter": [
                "messenger/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"
              ]}}
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've already spent 2 full days of digging into AWS docs, blog posts, and what not. This seems to me like such a normal, regular use case for AWS IoT topics, and yet so hard to get right.

Comment: Have you got a working solution?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 cases when using cognito with AWSIoT:

1. Cognito Authenticated Pool:
   In this case, you can define a policy at pool level which is less restrictive.
   Now, you need to attach a policy to every cognito user(IoT's AttachPolicy call) to give specific permissions to the cognito user.

Note: If you don't specify any IoT policy, everything is considered deny which seems to be the case if you are using authenticated pool cognito identities.

2. Cognito Unauthenticated Pool:
   In this case, IoT does not do any scopedown(IoT's AttachPolicy call in not required) and policy at the pool level will determine what user can do with IoT resources.

Details of this are present at:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/pub-sub-policy.html#pub-sub-policy-cognito
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/authorization.html

Another Similar thread you might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47838529/962545

Comment: Thanks for answering! I've come across that thread you mention, but I don't understand what it ultimately means. The answer in the forum makes zero sense to me.

The above policy (in my question) is attached to an _unauthenticated user pool_. What is wrong with it? Is it the `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}` variable?

Comment: I think two things are wrong actually
1. Your Deny statement is overriding the allow statement as your condition might not be valid at all (I don't think "iot:topicfilter" is a valid context key, from where did you get it?). Also Things subscribe to "topicfilters" while they publish/receive on "topics" so condition on topic filter doesn't sound right.
2. Your Cognito variable might be making the topic arn invalid thus resulting deny.
Try simulating your policy https://policysim.aws.amazon.com